# JQuery dynamic selector not working in ajaxForm()

Tags: jquery

Maybe this question was answered before but I couldn't fit my problem to the other answers, but indeed I did research.

I am using ajaxForm (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and I want to use the same function to submit multiples forms, but my jQuery selector is not working:

$('#' + idForm).ajaxForm({

I don't know what else I can do except than ask you guys.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hRTcE/

HTML:

```
<form id="jsonForm" action="/echo/json/" method="post">Message:
    <input type="text" name="message" value="Hello JSON" />
    <input id="HHHHHHHHH" type="button" onclick="formSubmit(this)" value="onclick not working">
    <input type="submit" value="submit is working" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
function formSubmit(inputB) {
    alert('click does not work');
    var formulario = inputB.form;
    var idForm = inputB.form.id;
    var test = $('#jsonForm');

    //debugger;
    $('#' + idForm).ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: processJson
    });
    return false;
}

function processJson(data) {
    //debugger;
    alert("it worked" + data);
    console.log("respose: " + data);
}
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    //debugger;
    var queryString = $.param(formData);
    console.log('About to submit: \n' + queryString + '\n');
    return true;
}
$('#jsonForm').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSubmit: showRequest,
    success: processJson
});
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ajaxSubmit instead of ajaxForm inside your formSubmit method

ajaxForm only prepares the form .it does not submit

You can do like this

```
function formSubmit(inputB) {
    alert('click does not work');
    var formulario = inputB.form;
    var idForm = inputB.form.id;
    var test = $('#jsonForm');

    //debugger;
    $('#' + idForm).ajaxSubmit({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: processJson
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you just forget to call submit on your form when the button is clicked?

Like so:

```
function formSubmit(inputB) {
    alert('click does not work');
    var formulario = inputB.form;
    var idForm = inputB.form.id;
    var test = $('#jsonForm');

    //debugger;
    $('#' + idForm).ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: processJson
    });
    $('#' + idForm).submit();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to acces form bu another way? For example :

```
var formulario = $(inputB).parent('form');
var idForm = $(formulario).attr('id');

$('#' + idForm).ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSubmit: showRequest,
    success: processJson
});

//Just add this
$('#' + idForm).submit();

return false;
```

**[EDIT]**

Just add this lines like below:

```
    //Just add this
    $('#' + idForm).submit();
```

It works on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hRTcE/6/)